# Insert data a into DB2 database from Oracle ResultSet without iterations

Tags: java, oracle, unix, db2, resultset

I have a weird problem that I need to solve, I have a Result Set in Java with data from one Oracle DB, and I need to insert this data into a DB 2 table. Both, the query and the DB2 Table has the same structure, but there's too many records (More than 200k) so make it with an iteration is too slow.

I want to do something like:

```
Connection DB2Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Url,Usr,Pwd);

ResultSet rs_oracle = statement.executeQuery("Select * from ORACLE.table1");
ResultSet rs_db2 = statement2.executeQuery("Select * from DB2.table2")
/*PSEUDO*/
rs_db2 += rs_oracle;

DB2Connection.commit();
```

And insert all the records from the rs_oracle into the DB2 Table.

There's any way to do it without an iteration?

Comment: Why dont you export the data and do a bulk import into DB2?

Comment: Yes, the problem is the iteration, not the hundreds of thousands of records...

Comment: And maybe you can connect one database to the other... in SQL Anywhere you could setup proxy tables, I do not know if it is available for DB2 or Oracle

Comment: Are you trying to combine the results from both databases and return them to the client?  Or are you trying to INSERT the records from Oracle into the DB2 table?  Your pseudo-code sure looks like you're just trying to combine the result sets for the client only.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a prepared statement and do a batch insert on that.